# How can I get the text of the selected item from a dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

How can I get the text of the selected item from a dropdown using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following URL, I came up with this solution:

http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg17717.html

```
$("#myDropdown option:selected").text()
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it seems to work great.

Comment: using the > selector is overkill and would actually break the script if you used `<optgroup>` elements.  Just make it `#myDropdown option:selected` intead.

Comment: Great idea!  I always seem to forget about the additional elements you can throw inside the select element!